# Pseudo random number

Tags: random, pseudocode

I need to find a function **f(t)** which generates pseudo random numbers in range **[0;1)** with uniform distribution. Results for same **t** must be equals.

Comment: The topic of [pseudorandom number generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) is huge and varied, with many different algorithms. Pick one that exists and has documented good characteristics; don't roll your own and don't rely on whatever the most convenient one for your system is, unless it comes with the aforementioned documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a linear congruential generator might be the way to go.

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: Many of the examples use an LCG with parameters that the site *itself* admits are awful (and "historical"). Let the reader beware.